# python pyautogui cannot print @

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a problem with Python pyautogui. I am trying to write a program to send email.

```
 pyautogui.hotkey('win', 's')
 pyautogui.typewrite('Outlook 2013')
 pyautogui.press('enter')
 time.sleep(25)
 pyautogui.press('esc')
 pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'h', 'n')
 pyautogui.typewrite(r'americussmile@gmail.com; 
 phuongduyen210492@gmail.com')
```

When it is run, the program types in Outlook's "To" box, but the email looks like this: **americussmilegmail.com and phuongduyen210492gmail.com**

I do not know what the problem is. I have tried to use @ and (r'') but it still does not work. Can someone help me with it?

FYI, my computer is a Scandinavian computer with ö and ä letters, so when you want to type @ you have to press "altgr +2" instead of "shift 2" as for a normal computer.

Comment: What error are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a string literal for the @ sign if it is not showing for you for some reason. Is your text file saved as ASCII or UTF-8, if not then this may be your problem and the @ sign is represented as a multi-byte character instead of with the correct ASCII code.

Anyway the string literal for the @ sign in python would be `'\x40'`.